# Positivity result from the strong maximum principle

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

In Evans PDE textbook(page 27), it said if $U$ is connected and $u \in C^2(U)\cap C(\bar U)$ satisfies:$\Delta u = 0$ in $U$ and $u=g$ on $\partial U$, where $g \geq 0$. Then, $u$ is positive everywhere in $U$ if $g$ is positive somewhere on $\partial U$. I don't see why. I know the maximum is always achived on the boundary unless it's constant within $U$, but I don't see how they are related here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If $g(x)>0$  for some $x \in \partial U$,then since $u\in C(\bar U)$ we know $u$ must be positive at interior points sufficiently close to $x$. Now apply the strong maximum principle to $-u$, which tells us we must be in one of two cases: either

- $u$ is constant, and thus positive everywhere since we know it's positive near $x$; or
- $u$ does not achieve its minimum anywhere in (the interior of) $U$. Since $u \ge 0$ on the boundary this implies $\min_{\bar U} u \ge0$, and thus $u>0$ in the interior.